# How to scrape Facebook page without getting blocked

Tags: python, web-scraping, visualization, sentiment-analysis

I tried to scrape a group on Facebook, while logged into my Fb account. The goal was to perform sentiment analysis on comments to the posts in the group.

On the first attempt, my account got blocked by Facebook. After retrieving the account, I tried again. This time, I received "`WARNING:facebook_scraper.page_iterators:No raw posts (<article> elements) were found in this page`". How do I overcome this challenge?

Attached is the code I used

```
import scipy as sp
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob as tb
import time
```

```
cookies = {"c_user": "1000092631152643",
"xs":"33%3AQklvQk0aNZ5TWw%3A2%3A1667187574%3A-1%3A1593AAcVH4RpjVV3E7"
}
```

```
listposts = []
options = {"comments": True, "reactors": True, "progress": True, "posts_per_page": 200}
group_id = 944651605603625
for post in get_posts(group = group_id, extra_info = True, pages = 100, options = options, cookies=cookies):
    print(post['text'][:50])
    time.sleep(20)
    listposts.append(post)
```

Comment: If your goal is to not get blocked by Facebook, then you play by their rules and use [their API](https://developers.facebook.com/). Scraping their site is not a good way to make friends with them.